# Find all real polynomials such that $p(x)=p(\alpha x)$ for some $\alpha>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

for $p(x)$ we write
$$
p(x)=a_{0} x^{0}+a_{1} x^{1}+a_{2} x^{2}+\ldots+a_{n} x^{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{j} x^{j}
$$
and for $p(\alpha x)$
$$
p(\alpha x)=a_{0}(\alpha x)^{0}+a_{1}(\alpha x)^{1}+a_{2}(\alpha x)^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}(\alpha x)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(\alpha x)^{k}: \alpha>0
$$
If $\alpha=1$, then  $p(x)=p(\alpha x)$. I'm not sure how to prove when $\alpha \neq 1$ or how to apply induction in this.

Comment: So given $\alpha>0$, find all polynomials that satisfy that?

Comment: Are you 100% sure? The current version seems a bit dubious.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ given to you as fixed or do you have to find polynomials for which there exists an $\alpha$ such that $p(x) = p(\alpha x)$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan $\alpha$ is not fixed, its for all the polynomials which there exists an $\alpha$ such that $p(x)=p(\alpha x)$

Comment: The only polynomials I can think of are constant polynomials

Comment: Is this an exercise in induction or are you trying an inductive approach?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I was trying an inductive approach but I don't know if its possible, the obvious part for me is when $\alpha=1,$ but I don't know how to prove when $\alpha$ is different from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let degree of polynomial be $n$

For $n = 0$ - constant polynomial would satisfy the property

For $n>0$

$$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n$$

$$p(\alpha x) - p(x) = a_1(\alpha-1)x + a_2(\alpha^2-1)x^2 +...+a_n(\alpha^n-1)x^n = 0$$

Since this is true for all $x$, the coefficients must be equal, i.e

$$a_1(\alpha-1) = 0$$

$$a_2(\alpha^2-1) = 0$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$a_n(\alpha^n-1) = 0$$

Hence either $\alpha =1$, or $a_i = 0$

Hence only the constant polynomial satisfies the above

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a nonconstant polynomial and $\alpha \neq 1$, then the polynomial $p(x)$ is distinct from the polynomial $p(\alpha x)$. This can be seen by noting $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{p(\alpha x)}{p(x)} = \alpha^{\text{deg p}} \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Each constant polynomial is always a solution to $\mathbf E:f(x)=f(\alpha x)$. Furthermore, if $\alpha=1$ then all real polynomials solve $\mathbf E$. However, if $1\neq\alpha>0$ then the only solutions to $\mathbf E$ are the constant polynomials because $\mathbf E\implies f(\alpha)=f(\alpha^n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and thus $f(x)$ is constant because $f(x)-f(\alpha)$ has infinitely many roots.